# Sym not defined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, adobe, animate-cc

I'm new to Adobe Animate CC and using Javascript/Jquery. I'm following [this tutorial](https://paultrani.com/2014/07/creating-drag-and-drop-functionality-with-edge-animate/) to create drag and drop items and have Jquery and JqueryUI loaded in my project. When I try to call a symbol using sym.$("symName") I am receiving sym not defined in the browser dev tools when I try to preview in Chrome. What am I missing? How can I get sym to access my library symbols?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This would suggest some library is not loading properly. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve We will need a more complete example to assist further.

Comment: sym.$("thumb").draggable(); is the code I'm attempting to use
I have imported jquery-ui-1.12.1 and jquery-3.3.1.min.js and receiving no errors as far as loading those library in the console of developer tools.

Comment: Based on the tutorial, `sym.$("thumb").draggable();`, should work successfully as long as `"thumb"` is an object. The error seems to be related to `sym` not loading, not *jquery* or *jquery ui*.